# Trigger function from another function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Hi i have two functions in Apps Script, when the first function is done i whould like the second one to be triggered, is it possible?

```
function sendEmail() {

 var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
 var message = firstThread.getMessages()[0];
 var sender = message.getFrom();
  var body = "Detta mail är ursprungligen skickat från" + " " + sender + '\n' + message.getBody();
 var subject = message.getSubject();
 var attachment = message.getAttachments();
  GmailApp.sendEmail("user.name@adje.com", subject, "",  {htmlBody: body, attachments: attachment});

  Logger.log(body);
}

function markArchivedAsRead() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:unread -label:inbox');
  GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
};
```

Comment: Just call the other function in the end of the first? e.g. `function sendEmail() { /* ... code ... */ markArchivedAsRead(); }`

Answer (score 0):

As Henrique said, you just need to call the function you made as below

```
 function sendEmail() {
     var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
     var message = firstThread.getMessages()[0];
     var sender = message.getFrom();
     var body = "Detta mail är ursprungligen skickat från" + " " + sender + '\n' + message.getBody();
     var subject = message.getSubject();
     var attachment = message.getAttachments();
     GmailApp.sendEmail("user.name@adje.com", subject, "",  {htmlBody: body, attachments: attachment});

     Logger.log(body);
     markArchivedAsRead();
    }

    function markArchivedAsRead() {
      var threads = GmailApp.search('label:unread -label:inbox');
      GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
    };
```